# Integration of two time series to produce a binary output

Tags: r

I have two time series in different dataframes R and I would like to integrate them in a binary fashion. 
One series (that I shall call S1) is time points every two minutes over a long period.

The other series is times that may be recorded at any stage (I shall call this S2).
I trying to integrate these in a manner so that if an event from S2 has occurred within the preceding 2 minutes from a point in S1 I am given a 1 (and a corresponding 0 if no event).

i.e

```
S1$time                            
11:01:46        
11:03:46
11:05:46
11:07:46 
11:09:46 
11:11:46 

S2$time
10:00:12.10
11:03:12.20
11:05:50.10
11:08:10.00
```

Would become:

```
S1$time       binary
11:01:46      0  
11:03:46      1
11:05:46      0
11:07:46      1
11:09:46      1
11:11:46      0
```

Reproducible example data:

```
 time<-c("11:01:46","11:03:46","11:05:46","11:07:46","11:09:46","11:11:46")
 S1<-as.data.frame(time)
 time<-c("10:00:12.10","11:03:12.20","11:05:50.10","11:08:10.00")
 S2<-as.data.frame(time)
```

I'm just not terribly sure how to go about this - I tried to give all the S2 variables the positive binary response and then merging the dataframes as in:

```
 bin<-rep(1,4)
 S2$binary<-bin
 merge(S1,S2,by="time")
```

But this seems to only work where the times in S1 and S2 are exactly the same? 
Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to convert the times into timestamps:

```
S1$ts <- as.POSIXct(S1$time, format = "%H:%M:%S")
S2$ts <- as.POSIXct(S2$time, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

In order to do the counts, you can use `sapply()` over all the timestamps in `S1`. The code takes advantage of the fact that you can simply add or subract seconds from a `POSIXct` time stamp:

```
S1$counts <- sapply(S1$ts, function(t)
                    as.numeric(any(S2$ts < t & S2$ts >= t - 120)))
S1
##       time                  ts counts
## 1 11:01:46 2016-03-02 11:01:46      0
## 2 11:03:46 2016-03-02 11:03:46      1
## 3 11:05:46 2016-03-02 11:05:46      0
## 4 11:07:46 2016-03-02 11:07:46      1
## 5 11:09:46 2016-03-02 11:09:46      1
## 6 11:11:46 2016-03-02 11:11:46      0
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed! I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming these are each sorted, but if not, sort `s2` first. Then you can find the nearest `s2` for each `s1` with `findInterval`.

```
s1 <- strptime(c("11:01:46","11:03:46","11:05:46","11:07:46","11:09:46","11:11:46"),
               format="%T")
s2 <- strptime(c("10:00:12.10","11:03:12.20","11:05:50.10","11:08:10.00"),
               format="%T")

data.frame(s1=format(s1,"%T"),flag=as.numeric(s1 - s2[findInterval(s1,s2)] < 120))
```

```
        s1 flag
1 11:01:46    0
2 11:03:46    1
3 11:05:46    0
4 11:07:46    1
5 11:09:46    1
6 11:11:46    0
```